# how to bind the same vector multiple times?

Tags: r

How can I bind the same vector `o = c(1,2,3,4)` multiple times to get a matrix like:

```
o = array(c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), dim(c(4,3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4
```

In a nicer way than: `o = cbind(o,o,o)` and maybe more generalized (`duplicate`)? I need this to specify colors for elements in `textplot`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

R recycles. It's very eco-friendly:

```
o=c(1,2,3,4) 
> matrix(o,nrow = 4,ncol = 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: +1 Just to be on the safe side I'd recommend `matrix(o,nrow = length(o),ncol = 4)` to prevent potentially unintended results like `matrix(o,nrow = 3,ncol = 4)`

Answer (score 15):

You can use `replicate`

```
> o = c(1,2,3,4) 
> replicate(4, o)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: Although the answer by @joran is more "R", I prefer this as it reads better. I find this important when explaining my scripts to colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer

```
outer(1:4,1:4,function(x,y)x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: or, a lot neater:  `1:4 %o% rep(1, 3)`