# Replicate Matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix with dimension

```
M[360,180,120]
M <- array(0, dim = c(360,180,120))
```

and another one with dimension

```
C[360,180,12]
C <- array(0, dim = c(360,180,12))
```

What I would like to do is to create a matrix with the dimension of M that stores the values of C, e.g.

```
N[,,1] = C[,,1]
N[,,2] = C[,,2]
.
.
N[,,12] = C[,,12]
N[,,13] = C[,,1]
.
.
N[,,120] = C[,,12]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does this recycling automatically.

```
C <- array(1:(360*180*12), dim = c(360,180,12))
N <- array(C, dim = c(360,180,120))

identical(N[,,120],C[,,12])
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693349/how-to-bind-the-same-vector-multiple-times/13693361#13693361 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555651/under-what-circumstances-does-r-recycle/6555764#6555764